# How can I delete the comma inserted in textarea by Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to put 1 line of array in line but this happens:

```js
array = ["item", "item2"]
$('#textarea').val(array.map(x=> x+'\n'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
```

I need the `,` to be removed.

Comment: please do not add any images showing here and use a snippet instead

Comment: How can I use snippets?

Comment: @pepitolamueve for future reference, [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do/358993#358993) is how you add a code snippet

Comment: Thank you to you two @NickParsons I'm new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.map` returns an array. When you set the value of an element, the parameter is coerced to a string, and an array, when coerced to a string, adds `,`s between each element.

Use `.join` instead:

```
$('#textarea').val(array.join('\n'));
```

```js
array = ["item", "item2"]
$('#textarea').val(array.join('\n'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
```

Comment: Perfect! many thanks, I will give you the right answer in 10 minutes, I'm new!